# Mac cancelUserAttentionRequest not working?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I can't seem to get cancelUserAttentionRequest to work. I have the following...

.mm file

```
void SetNotify()
{
    this->notify = [NSApp requestUserAttention:NSCriticalRequest];
}

void RemoveNotify()
{
    if (!this->notify) {
        return;
    }

    [NSApp cancelUserAttentionRequest:this->notify];
}
```

header

```
protected:
    int notify;
```

And I'm using a timer to call SetNotify, then another timer which runs 5 seconds later. The icon bounces fine, but it doesn't stop bouncing. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `if (!this->notify)` check.

The documentation for `requestUserAttention:` says nothing about the nature of the integer it returns (it could be *any* valid integer), and the current implementation returns `0` for the first request. If you need to be sure `SetNotify()` is called before `RemoveNotify()`, use a separate boolean flag.

(Also, you should store the return value in an `NSInteger`, not an `int`.)